# Check for an images existence before allowing it into a json string?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I have a database of names coupled with URL's to images that are uploaded by the user to my server, i then have a page which does a

```
SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 0,65
```

or to that a effect, echoes a 'json_encode' string, finally my Android application gets and parses the information it finds.

The problem lies, when for instance, say the upload of the image failed or the image goes missing for whatever reason, the database still HAS the link to this missing file, and as such when my app attempts to load the image it is caught with an error.

PHP:

```
while($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) 
{           
    $date = $info['date_time'];
    $info['date_time'] = time_ago($date);
    $img = $info['url'];
    if (!@getimagesize($img)) 
    {
        $info['url'] = "";
    }
    $rows[] = $info;
}
    $data = array('UserNames' => $rows);
    echo json_encode($data);
```

NOW, i know this is VERY bad, since if it has 65 results it has to iterate over every result, check for existence and then crudely replace the value of url before its encoded, however IS there a better way to ensure a broken link does not get through to the json encode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest decoupling the "does this image exist?" from the api method returning the images. You can do this several ways:

- If the image upload failed, there shouldn't be an image reference available at all. You can do this by not setting an URL value before you can confirm that the image has been uploaded as it should.
- If the user is allowed to put in a random URL, check the URL when the user updates it and that it's valid then.
- Each night, check a selection of the images (depending on the total number of links) for validity. If it's just 65 images, check all of them. If it's 650000, spread it out a bit.
- Let your Android app discover if the image doesn't load: if the image fails to load, send another request that tells your app to check the validity of the image and display a placeholder in your app instead. That way you get distributed image existence checking when you're displaying it by the users, and you only check problematic images.

At least, move it out from the display loop. That's going to kill your api real quick.